# How can I properly load my project's classes in order of dependencies?

Tags: java, dependency-management

I'm developing a project in Java, and I'm looking to load modules in order of how they require each other. The way the module loader works is it looks in the `modules` folder, from there, it loops through the folders, and finds a `module.json` in each of them. In that file, there is a section as follows:

```
"dependencies": [
 "AModuleDependency"
]
```

It uses the name of a module, and that module MUST be loaded before this one is. I have no idea how I would cascade this process correctly. Some modules don't have any dependencies (in which case the `dependencies` wouldn't be there), and some modules have MANY dependencies. Is there any way to easily convey this process in Java. Thanks. If you don't fully understand. I'll give an example.

(modules dir)

```
modules /
  ModuleOne /
    module.jar
    pango.json -> dependencies -> ModuleW
  ModuleW
    module.jar
    pango.json -> dependencies -> ModuleZ
  ModuleZ
    module.jar
    pango.json
```

The module loader would WANT to load ModuleOne, ModuleW, and then ModuleZ (due to looping through files being alphabetical), but it should be loaded in the order of which dependencies it requires.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "load a module"? Why not add all those jars to classpath and let ClassLoader resolve any dependencies?

Comment: From a design perspective point, `ModuleOne` should only care about loading `ModuleW`, and `ModuleW` should only care about loading `ModuleZ`. Thus, you would get your dependency order "for free". This, of course, only works if you have a cycle-free dependency graph (which should always be the case).

Comment: @Piotr Praszmo I'm using URLClassLoader to load the jars, but how would it resolve dependencies? I'm running methods from a module as soon as I load it which means that if a dependency isn't loaded, it won't run the method successfully. Maybe, I could load all the jars, and then run their methods so no matter what order it's in, the dependencies are available? edit: Just realized that my software is already built in a way that all the modules are loaded, and then the methods are invoked, so there isn't a need for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively loop through your dependencies. Go through them, eliminate the ones which have their dependencies already loaded (in the beginning, it'll only be the ones which don't have any dependencies). Then you can keep going, more dependencies will be loaded and then soon, all of them.

Here's a visual representation of how it would go.
First cycle:

```
Plugin1 : Depends on Plugin3 and Plugin4
Plugin2 : Depends on nothing             X (all of their dependencies are already loaded)
Plugin3: Depends on Plugin2
Plugin4: Depends on nothing              X
```

Second cycle:

```
Plugin1 : Depends on Plugin3 and Plugin4
Plugin3: Depends on Plugin2              X (all of its dependencies have already been loaded)
```

Third cycle:

```
Plugin1 : Depends on Plugin3 and Plugin4 X (all of its dependencies have already been loaded)
```

Now everything is loaded in the correct order! Since you tagged this with Java, I'll also write a code example.

```java
private final List<Plugin> unloadedPlugins;
private final List<Plugin> loadedPlugins;

public void loadPlugins() {
  List<Plugin> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Plugin plugin : unloadedPlugins) {
    if (loadedPlugins.containsAll(plugin.getDependencies()) {
      plugin.load();
      loadedPlugins.add(plugin);
      toRemove.add(plugin);
    }
  }

  unloadedPlugins.removeAll(toRemove);

  if (unloadedPlugins.size > 0) loadDependencies();
}
```

You'll also want to do a check to make sure that all the dependencies are present, otherwise that method will keep looping.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Maven and a [Multi-Module Project](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module)?

You can find examples of multi-modules projects on GitHub, like this one: [maven-surefire](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire) and [its list of modules](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/pom.xml#L50).

Comment: Projects are loaded dynamically and also, modules won't be publicly available so using Maven isn't an option. Thanks for the suggestion though.